# Possible missing firmware amdgpu

Tags: 22.04, amdgpu

When I run `sudo prime-select intel` I get the following warning

```
$ sudo prime-select intel
Info: selecting the intel profile
Updating the initramfs. Please wait for the operation to complete:
|W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/ip_discovery.bin for module amdgpu
\W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega10_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_cap.bin for module amdgpu
/W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_toc.bin for module amdgpu
|W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
Done
```

I checked the other answers that where similar and they all suggested around the same thing, which was to [go here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amdgpu) and copy over the missing files.

Unfortunately, none of the files I get a warning about are there

Comment: Well, as the name suggests, "amdgpu" is for AMD GPUs. Since you, apparently, have an intel GPU, what's missing for anything else is a moot point. ...and if there is an AMD GPU, you need to check which one. Also, there are lots of firmware files in `/lib/firmware/amdgpu/`.

Comment: @mikewhatever `prime-select intel` is nvidia's driver managment, and the only option is intel for cpu, not amd.  In terms of saying there are lots of firmware files in lib/firm/amdgpu as I said with the link the missing ones are no where to be found in the linux kerenel site..

Comment: So, for the sake of clarity, do you need amdgpu firmware for Nvidia GPU or Intel CPU?

Comment: @mikewhatever  This is the laptop, https://www.razer.com/gaming-laptops/razer-blade-14 Which has a AMD Ryzen™ 9 6900HX and NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 3080 Ti

Comment: @mikewhatever and to clarify, I presume I need the AMD files, which are not where it says to look for them.  Despite NVIDIA calling "intel" I presume that is their code for just CPU...

Comment: maybe related: https://community.frame.work/t/resolved-amd-7640u-debian-12-external-monitor-no-longer-working/40526

Answer (score 2):

This is probably normal, to see the installed firmware files run this command:

```
ls -l /lib/firmware/amdgpu/
```

You can also check the output from 'dmesg' to see if any amdgpu firmware failed to load during boot, if no related errors then these warnings can be ignored.

```
sudo dmesg | grep amdgpu
```